# How do I make 2d- Flashlight effect in Processing 3

Tags: java, background, processing, mask

For reference the effect I'm going for is this:
[image: Pokemon Cave Effect]

I'm working in Processing 3, NOT p5.js. 
I've looked around processing forums, but i can't find anything that works in the current version or doesn't use PGraphics and a mask which from what I've read can be expensive to use.

My current ideas and implementations have resulted to drawing shapes around the player and filling the gaps in with a circles with no fill that has a large stroke weight.

Does anyone know of any methods to easily and inexpensively draw a black background over everything except a small circular area?

If this is the wrong place to ask this question just send me on my way I guess, but please be nice. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an image (or `PGraphics`) that consists of mostly black, with a transparent circle in it. This is called [image masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Image_masks) or [alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing). Doing a Google image search for "alpha composite" returns a bunch of the images I'm talking about.

Anyway, after you have the image, it's just a matter of drawing it on top of your scene wherever the player is. You might also use the `PImage#mask()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html).